# How to iterate through datasource to create Querybuilder filters

Tags: jquery, json

I'm new to jQuery/JSON.  I am using mistic100's querybuilder but I'm unsure how to load the filters from a data source.  In this example, 3 filters are loaded into the builder.  Syntax-wise, how would I do this from a data source?  I guess I'm just not understanding how to iterate through all of the filters if they are in a data source.

```
    $('#builder-basic').queryBuilder({
      plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],

      filters: [{
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
      }, {
        id: 'category',
        label: 'Category',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'select',
        values: {
          1: 'Books',
          2: 'Movies',
          3: 'Music',
          4: 'Tools',
          5: 'Goodies',
          6: 'Clothes'
        },
        operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null',     'is_not_null']
      }, {
        id: 'in_stock',
        label: 'In stock',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'radio',
        values: {
          1: 'Yes',
          0: 'No'
        },
        operators: ['equal']
      }
      }],
      rules: rules_basic
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a filter in the GUI, you can save this filter;

```
var myFilter = $('#builder-basic').queryBuilder('getRules');
```

You can store this back to your datastore just like you would any other data. You will probably want to serialize it;

```
var myFilterString="";
if (!$.isEmptyObject(myFilter)) {myFilterString =JSON.stringify(genResult, null, 2);
```

Then later if you need to show this data, you can pull the rule as a string and deserialize it, and use setRules to show the rule in the GUI.

```
$('#builder-basic').queryBuilder('setRules', JSON.parse(myFilterString));
```

If you are just wanting to set a rule that wasnt created using the GUI, you simply need to create an object of the required structure and use setrules - or define it in string format, deserialize and use setrules.

The JSON looks like this

```
var rules_widgets = {
  condition: 'OR',
  rules: [{
    id: 'date',
    operator: 'equal',
    value: '1991/11/17'
  },     {
    id: 'rate',
    operator: 'equal',
    value: 22
  }, {
    id: 'category',
    operator: 'equal',
    value: '38'
  }, {
    condition: 'AND',
    rules: [{
      id: 'coord',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 'B.3'
    }]
  }]
};
```